# Parameters are not getting updated on Blazor Dynamic Component

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

Updating my explanation from suggestions from @MrC aka Shaun Curtis

I have a Blazor page index that is referencing Blazor component Display. Display is creating a dynamic component of Blazor page Alert and passing some parameters. I can confirm that during initialization of index, component Display passes the parameter values to alert but any subsequent values for similar keys are not passed to alert;

Alert:

```
@page "/Alert"

@if (this.Message is not null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-primary">
        @this.Message
    </div>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public string? SiteId{ get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string? SiteName {get; set;}
    private string Message = siteId + " " + SiteName;
}
```

Display:

```
<DynamicComponent Type=@this.ComponentType Parameters=@ComponentParameters />

@code

{
    [Parameter] public Type? ComponentType { get; set; }
    private Dictionary<string, object?> ComponentParameters { get; set; } = new();


        /// <summary>
        /// Updates the parameters and invoke state has changed
        /// </summary>
        public void UpdateParameters(string val1, string val2)
        {
            ComponentParameters = new()
            {
               {"SiteId", val1??string.Empty},
               {"SiteName", val2??string.Empty}
            };
            StateHasChanged();
        }
}
```

Index:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.
<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-success" @onclick=this.SetMessaage>Set</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick=this.ClearMessaage>Clear</button>
</div>

<Display ComponentType=_componentType @ref="_display1"></Display>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string SiteId {get;set;} = default!;
    [Parameter] public string SiteName {get; set;} = default!;
    Display _display1 = default!; 
    private Type _componentType = typeof(Alert);

    private void SetMessaage()
    {
        _display1.UpdateParameters("hello","world");
    }

    private void ClearMessaage()
    {
        _display1.UpdateParameters("","");
    }
}
```

Someone mentioned using @Key but I have no idea how to implement that to this example.

Comment: The revised code doesn't compile.  If you want a definitive answer then please provide code that compiles and works -     `private string Message = siteId + " " + SiteName;`  Should be     `private string Message => siteId + " " + SiteName;`.  Once you make this change it works!

Answer (score 0):

As your example is basically pseudo code rather than a [MRE] then it's impossible to pinpoint your problem.

Here's a *Mininal Reproducible Example*, based on your question, I believe demonstrates what you want to achieve.  It works, so I may be wrong!.

Clicking the buttons in the page changes or clears the message passed in the parameters.  The component reacts as expected, updating the message or hiding when there's nothing to display.

A component - `Alert` - your `C`.

```cs
@if (this.Message is not null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-primary">
        @this.Message
    </div>
}
@code {
    [Parameter] public string? Message { get; set; }
}
```

A component using `Dynamic` - `Display` - your `B`.

```cs
<DynamicComponent Type=this.ComponentType Parameters=this.ComponentParameters />

@code {
    [Parameter] public Type? ComponentType { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Dictionary<string, object?> ComponentParameters { get; set; } = new();
}
```

And finally `Index` to demo it - your `A`.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.
<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-success" @onclick=this.SetMessaage>Set</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick=this.ClearMessaage>Clear</button>
</div>

<Display ComponentType=_componentType ComponentParameters=_parameters />

@code {
    private string? Message;

    private Dictionary<string, object?> _parameters = new();
    private Type _componentType = typeof(Alert);

    private void SetMessaage()
    {
        _parameters = new() { { "Message", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() } };
    }

    private void ClearMessaage()
    {
        _parameters = new() { { "Message", null } };
    }
}
```

Note:

You use a lot of null forgiving in your code.

This just sets `Key1` to null and tells the compiler - "ignore null checking on Key1, I know what I'm doing".  Is that really your intent?

```cs
public string Key1 {get; set;} = default!;
```

This is a valid use:

```cs
[Inject] public MyService MyServiceInstane {get; set;} = default!;
```

because the Renderer will throw an error if it can't find a service to inject, so by the time you use it, it can't be null, so you can dispense will null checking in your code.

In your code above that's probably not the case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have gone ahead and updated my original question to incorporate your example for easier comprehension. My example looks very similar to yours except for few minor changes but I would expect it to work and it does for the first time but not for subsequent changes in parameters

Yes, I am using null forgiving because I am taking care of these null values with null-coalescing operator

Comment: See my comment on the revised question.